# Are there some way to prevent the console flashing when clear screen?

Tags: c++, c, windows, console

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define Speed 60
#define map_height 20
#define map_width 20
char KeyPress(){
    if(_kbhit() ){
    return _getch();
    };
    return -1;
}
void moveRight(int (*map)[map_height]){
    int _x;int _y;
    char current;
    for(int y = 0; y< map_height;y++){
            for(int x =0; x < map_width;x++){
                if(map[y][x] != NULL) {
                    _x = x; _y = y; current = map[y][x];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    map[_y][_x] = NULL;
    map[_y][_x+1] = current;
}
int main(){
    HANDLE output = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    int map[map_height][map_height] = {NULL};
    map[0][0] = 1;
    int pos = 0;
    //Draw map
    while(1){
    for(int y = 0; y< map_height;y++){
        for(int x =0; x < map_width;x++){
            if(map[y][x] == NULL) printf("[ ]");
            else printf("[x]");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    //End
    Sleep(Speed);
    //system("CLS");
    COORD pos = {0, 0};
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(output, pos);
    if(KeyPress() == 'd') moveRight(map);
    }
}
```

This is my psude code for my console game written by C, but when i run it game, it always flashing. How to prevent it flashing? both system("CLS") and Set ConsoleCursorPostion make it flashing .........................................................................................

Comment: If you don't want it to flash, then don't clear the screen. Think about it, if you quickly clear the screen and then draw it again, it will appear to be flashing. Why don't you just draw the entire screen each time without clearing it? Then the contents will be entirely replaced with no flashing

Comment: so i use SetConsoleCursorPosition(), that mean there are no clear screen, but it still happen (lesser)

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you mean by "flashing" exactly? Do you mean sometimes the characters you print are there and sometimes they aren't? Or do you mean sometimes areas are brighter?

Comment: In general the way to avoid flashing in graphics is to use the technique of "double buffering". For winapi console you could probably make use of the following to implement it in a console app http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131148/win32-c-console-clearing-screen-without-blinking

Comment: when i use system("cls"), it "blink" entire the screen (mean you see it appear and disappear in very short time), when i use SetConsoleCursorPosition to redraw it, it also "blink" but some area of the screen

Comment: Thank, problems solved by using "double bufferring"